# Is it acceptable to use the var() CSS function despite a error in CSS validators?

Tags: css, validation, formatting, coding-style

This is a CSS code for multiple use of a color variable.

```
:root {
  --borderColor: #707070;
}
.btn {
  border: 1px solid var(--borderColor, #707070);
}
```

When I run [CSS Validator](https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate), an error appears:

> Require use of known properties. Properties should be known (listed in
> CSS3 specification) or be a vendor-prefixed property.

Should I use the classic color usage or ignore the error?

```
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}
```

Comment: ignore the error

Comment: ... and use a [better validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) (tick the CSS box)

Answer (score 0):

CSS variables are part of the W3C standards (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/). Thus you can use them at ease.

> Should I use the classic color usage or ignore the error?

The classic use of colors is less powerful than css variables. You must therefore choose the one that best suits your needs.